# Show that $x^2 + y^2 + 1 \le \sqrt{(x^3 + y + 1)(y^3 + x + 1)}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For $x, y \ge 0$ prove that:

$$x^2 + y^2 + 1 \le \sqrt{(x^3 + y + 1)(y^3 + x + 1)}$$

What I think would apply is the AM-GM Inequality, so first,

$$(x^2 + y^2 + 1)^2 \le (x^3  + y + 1)(y^3 + x + 1)$$

$$\implies (x^3  + y + 1)(y^3 + x + 1) - (x^2 + y^2  + 1)^2 \ge 0$$

$$\implies x^3y^3 + x^3 - 2x^2y^2 - 2x^2 + xy + x + y^3 - 2y^2 + y \ge 0$$

From AM-GM,

$$\frac{ x^3y^3 + x^3 - 2x^2y^2 - 2x^2 + xy + x + y^3 - 2y^2 + y}{9} \ge \sqrt[9]{x^3y^3(x^3)(-2x^2y^2) (-2x^2)(xy) (x) (y^3) (- 2y^2) (y)}$$

The negative is the issue we have: $(-2x^2)(-2x^2y^2)(-2y^2)$ which is a problem.

How can this be done? **Please, HINTS only.**

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwartz inequation.

Comment: Use AM-GM inequality,$a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$,must $a,b\ge 0$

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:number-theory] tag for questions regarding inequalities for real numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Only use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality :
$$(a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+a^2_{3})(b^2_{1}+b^2_{2}+b^2_{3})\ge(a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3})^2$$
let $$a_{1}=x^{\frac{3}{2}},a_{2}=y^{\frac{1}{2}},a_{3}=1$$
$$b_{1}=x^{\frac{1}{2}},b_{2}=y^{\frac{3}{2}},b_{3}=1$$
so we have
$$(x^3+y+1)(x+y^3+1)\ge (x^2+y^2+1)^2$$
so
$$\sqrt{(x^3+y+1)(y^3+x+1)}\ge x^2+y^2+1$$

**Solution 2:**

you can also 
$$\Longleftrightarrow (x^3y^3-2x^2y^2+xy)+(x^3-2x^2+x)+(y^3-2y^2+y)\ge 0$$
since use AM-GM inequality
$$ x^3y^3+xy\ge 2\sqrt{x^3y^3\cdot xy}=2x^2y^2$$
$$x^3+x\ge 2\sqrt{x^3\cdot x}=2x^2$$
$$y^3+y\ge 2\sqrt{y^3\cdot y}=2y^2$$

Comment: How using cauchy-schwarz inequality? which version are you using? Because i  dont see how you got this?

Comment: hello,I have edit it.

Comment: that is a different definition of cauchy-schwartz you are using? The general definition definition online is different? Are you somehow using $\sum a_n^2 \sum b_n^2 \ge \left(  \sum a_n b_n \right)^2$ ?

Comment: Yes,I have use this.